# Converting epoch to a readable date/time format in Informix

Tags: sql, informix

I have a basic Informix query and would like to know if it's possible to convert the epoch time to something readable from with the sql query.  The field is `dateTimeOrigination`;

```
SELECT
    dateTimeOrigination,
    callingPartyNumber,
    finalCalledPartyNumber 
FROM tbl_billing_data 
WHERE finalCalledPartyNumber LIKE 'XXXX'
    OR callingpartynumber LIKE 'XXXX' 
ORDER BY datetimeOrigination
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the internal **dbinfo** function.  More about it, read the manual [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1495.htm)

```
select dbinfo('utc_to_datetime', dateTimeOrigination) ,
  callingPartyNumber,finalCalledPartyNumber 
from tbl_billing_data 
where finalCalledPartyNumber like 'XXXX' 
  or callingpartynumber like 'XXXX' 
order by datetimeOrigination
```

Comment: Hello, Ceinmart!  Thank you as always, this did the trick.